# Focus of a parabola

Tags: conic-sections

If (2,0) is the vertex and y-axis the directrix of a parabola find the focus of the parabola.
What does y-axis is directrix mean here?

Comment: See the third example in http://www.purplemath.com/modules/parabola3.htm

Comment: But we aren't provided with a value of directrix here.

Comment: What do you mean by "a value of directrix"?

Comment: Something like y= a constant

Answer (score 3):

The parabola is the locus of points that are equidistant from both a given line (the directrix) and a point (the focus).

[image]

Normally, you are given the data to give the results in terms of $x$: a directrix $y=\cdots$ for a parabola $y=\cdots$. But in this case, your directrix is $x=0$. Just try to follow the same directives but interchanging $x$ and $y$; you will obtain a parabola of the form $x=\cdots$ instead of $y=\cdots$